# How to increment the hadoop counter number

Tags: hadoop

As is well know that, the amount of hadoop counters is 120. I wanted to increase the number, I tried add the flowing in configuration:

```
mapreduce.job.counters.limit=1000
mapreduce.job.counters.max=1000
mapreduce.job.counters.groups.max=500
mapreduce.job.counters.group.name.max=1000
mapreduce.job.counters.counter.name.max=500
```

But, it didn't make sense. 
So do you guys know how to increase the counter number. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly you wanna do?

Comment: You know the maximum of hadoop counter is 120, I need to use more than 200 counters to test the performance, so the default value is not enough! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your configuration in all of your JobTracker, TaskTrackers and your client, and restart them. For example, `mapreduce.job.counters.limit` is only loaded to [Limits.COUNTERS_MAX](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/0.23.0-cdh4b1/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/counters/Limits.java#35) when they start.

Answer (score 0):

Although the actual part of your question has been answered, I would like to bring a couple of things to your notice :

> 1- Counters are very expensive since the JobTracker has to maintain
>   every counter of every map/reduce task for the entire duration of the
>   application. So use them wisely.
>
> 2- Since counters are stored in the JobTracker, there is a fair chance
>   that your JobTracker will go OOM with such high counter values. And
>   this is the reason behind keeping the number of counters, that can be
>   created per Job, limited by Hadoop.